# Load form data via REST into vue-form-generator

Tags: json, rest, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I am building a form, that needs to get data dynamically via a JSON request that needs to be made while loading the form. I don't see a way to load this data. Anybody out here who can help?

JSON calls are being done via vue-resource, and the forms are being generated via vue-form-generator.

```
export default Vue.extend({
  template,

  data() {
    return {
      model: {
        id: 1,
        password: 'J0hnD03!x4',
        skills: ['Javascript', 'VueJS'],
        email: 'john.doe@gmail.com',
        status: true
      },

      schema: {
        fields: [
          {
            type: 'input',
            inputType: 'text',
            label: 'Website',
            model: 'name',
            maxlength: 50,
            required: true,
            placeholder: companyList
          },
        ]
      },

      formOptions: {
        validateAfterLoad: true,
        validateAfterChanged: true
      },
      companies: []
    };
  },

  created(){
    this.fetchCompanyData();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchCompanyData(){
      this.$http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/load/dynamicly').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.company);
        let companyList = response.data.company; // Use this var above
      }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just assign `this.schema.fields.placeholder` to the value returned by the API like following:

```
  methods: {
    fetchCompanyData(){
      this.$http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/load/dynamicly').then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.company);
        this.schema.fields.placeholder = response.data.company
      }, (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: @MapDev Are you setting `this.model.company` somewhere?

Comment: Hey did find you solution I am also looking for something similar to this.

Comment: Hey did you find your solution can you please help me.

Comment: @DenisBhojvani What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I am facing issues is here If I am using  select input type so how can I set dynamically value property of that select box which array is coming from API call.

Comment: @DenisBhojvani You can set initial value of that variable empty array and populate it in beforeMount from the API call and use that variable in select box. If it does not work, Please create a question with more details so that it can be understood better and answered.

Comment: okay Thanks let me create question for this will provide you link here.